# Image with click effect

Tags: android, imageview, listener, ontouchlistener

I am trying to do click effect in my custom ImageView class AvatarView.

I am using that code:

```
        // **** Listener onTouch ****.

    // Añadimos un listener para su pulsación.
    this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 

                    // Establecemos un filtrado de color.
                    AvatarView.this.setColorFilter(0xe0f47521, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                    AvatarView.this.invalidate();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 

                    // Eliminamos el filtrado de color.
                    //AvatarView.this.clearColorFilter();
                    AvatarView.this.setColorFilter(null);
                    AvatarView.this.invalidate();
                    break;


            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

This code works perfectly in my 2.3 phone, but it fails in my 4.1 tablet since the image disappear and doesn't reappear.

I have not found any solution. Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution: it's necessary take the drawable:

```
        // **** Listener onTouch ****.

    // Añadimos un listener para su pulsación.
    this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 

                    // Establecemos un filtrado de color.
                    AvatarView.this.getDrawable().setColorFilter(0xe0f47521, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                    AvatarView.this.invalidate();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 

                    // Eliminamos el filtrado de color.
                    AvatarView.this.getDrawable().clearColorFilter();
                    AvatarView.this.invalidate();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: 

                    // Eliminamos el filtrado de color.
                    AvatarView.this.getDrawable().clearColorFilter();
                    AvatarView.this.invalidate();
                    break;

            }

            return false;
            //return true;
        }
    });
```

Now, it works fine.

Can anybody say me if I should return true or false? What's the difference?

Thanks.

Comment: false means the touch event hasnt been consumed, and therefore will be propagated to underlying views. True consumes the event so children wont be notified of the event